# Why do I see a "Put Back" menu item in the trash for only some items?

Tags: macos, finder, trash

When I control-click on some files in the trash I see the "Put Back" menu item:

[image]

However, on other files I don't see this item:

[image]

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only see Put Back if a file/folder was deleted by the Finder, not any other process.

It will silently fail to Put Back if the folder it came from is gone, but it will still offer.

Tested on Mojave.

Comment: Thanks. It's weird, I suddenly found a couple of those .AAE files in my trash but don't know where they came from. Searching for the file name (eg. "IMG_9082") doesn't reveal anything either.

Comment: An .AAE might have been discarded by the photo app used to edit the linked image. I tend to work in .NEF photos in Nikon's own software - if I discard images from there, it throws the NEF & the associated .nksc sidecar file in the trash, from where there is no Put Back.

Comment: At some earlier time there were Objective C APIs that did work but they stopped working and Apple haven't fixed them, Apps use these APIs and they just move the file to ~/.Trash without marking them for Put Back (they don't store the info in .DS_Store)

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin. I was looking through my photos library to find the original images with the same file name, but couldn't find anything that related to these .AAE files. It remains a mystery.